# url requested redirect but the

Tags: facebook, button

When I pass the url by the Facebook debugger I receive the "Critical error"
**"URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed."**
The redirected URL is the same as the Fetched and Canonical with the added **"?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1"**. So the link rejects this .
I tried the cookieless = UseCookies at Web.config in order to avoid the cookiesupport parameter in the URL but nothing happens , is still there.

this is the section in web.config :
     `<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies"/>`

Is this fine?
Another way for suppressing the parameter?
Its a Facebook cache issue?
You can try it :
 https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdisaweb.com%2FModulos%2Ftorre-noria-11.aspx

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You're link redirects to:

http://disaweb.com/modulos/torre-noria-11.aspx/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

but that returns a 302 to the same location. You can't return a 301 or a 302 to the exact same location that is requested.

Comment: can you widen the observation ? I'm not understanding what do you mean.thanks

Comment: Each time you make an HTTP request, you get an HTTP response. Your first link returns an HTTP response of 302 and gives a "Location" of another address. So, the browser's job is to load the new location. The problem is that the new location returns a 302 too. That in itself isn't so bad, but the 302 is returns is the same location as the request. In other words, it's saying to redirect to itself.

Comment: Im going to explain how I have the things: I have the Like button in a nested page . The data-ref property of the button points to the same URL  of the nested page. When you hit the button facebook point to that URL for the metatags (I´m right?) then a error box launchs with the Facebook problems in recover the needed data from that URL.
In the behind the only thing(in the debugger) I notice is that the UrL final is URL+?AspxAutoDetect...etc .And  So my questions are:
Is the Like Button setup right?
Is a server problem "URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed."?
Thanks

Comment: I changed this <anonymousIdentification cookieless="AutoDetect" enabled="true"/> for <anonymousIdentification cookieless="UseCookies" enabled="true"/> in the web.config and then the Facebook debugger returned code 200